# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a column `code` in dataframe `df` according to the first component of another column `other_column`, which include codes with either only numerical components, or letters followed by numerical components.

I used:

```
df['code'] = ['alphabet' if (x[0].isalpha() and not x.startswith("XY")) else 'non-alphabet' for x in df['other_column']]
```

so if the first component of the code is alphabet but does not start with `XY` then `code` is `alphabet`, otherwise(probably only numerical) `code` is `non-alphabet`.

It returned:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The problem is that the code worked for another dataframe which has the same `'other_column'` column. I am not sure what I have overlooked, and how can I check what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like your have missing data marked with `np.nan` which is a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you received an error when you were using the code.

First of all, it would be a better idea to split your code to multiple lines for better readability.

Secondly, I am sorry that I don't understand your code quite well, but you may try using the following code.

```py
for x in df['other_column']:
  if (x[0].isalpha() and not x.startswith("XY"):
    df['code'] = 'alphabet'
  else:
    df['code'] = 'non-alphabet'
```